# How fetch the array from return of query method of a resource in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have read the angularjs tutorial and now I am tryin to use in symfony application.
I've implemented a rest client resource. The response json object has a `sportEvents` property which is an array. It is fetched.

```
var sportServices = angular.module('sportServices', ['ngResource']);

sportServices.factory('sportClient', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('rest/sport/events.json', {}, {
      query: {
          method:'GET', 
          transformResponse: function (data) {return angular.fromJson(data).sportEvents},
          isArray: true // The sportEvents property is an array.
      }
    });
  }]);
```

And my controller:

```
var sportControllers = angular.module('sportControllers', []);

sportControllers.controller('SportEventListCtrl', ['$scope', 'sportClient',
    function($scope, sportClient) {
      $scope.sportEvents = sportClient.query();
}]);
```

`sportClient.query();` this is not an array, I cannot iterate it. And that's **my question how can I achieve that the sportClient.query() returns with an array?** because I have to group the elements and for this I need to iterate over the elements.

So a sample response:

```
{"sportEvents": [{id: 2234, number: 43545, name:"random"}, {id: 2235, number: 43546, name:"random"}]}
```

But this is the funny part:
`console.log( BetClient.query() );` in the controller the command gives the following result in the console:

```
[$promise: Object, $resolved: false]
```

And yes, in this object I see the entries, but I would like to transform it to an array somehow :)

Comment: Can you post a sample of the JSON being returned by your server-side code?

Comment: I have added, but it is not important, cause the sportClient.query(); does not return with the JSON array :) It retursn with a hell boy :D The angularJS automatically transform it an other json object, which will be iteratable for the view, but... hello :D I want to iterate it in the controller, and I cannot, this is my biggest problem :D

Comment: Did plunker help you out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything "major" wrong with your code but in case you receive `$promise`, then resolve it first instead of assigning it directly to `$scope.sportEvents`.

With asynchronous calls, like `$http`, you'll receive a promise that yes, something will be returned. When operation finishes, you can either resolve the promise for data or in case of error, reject it.

So this service

```
app.factory('JsonResource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('events.json', {}, {
    query: {
      method: 'GET',
      transformResponse: function(data) {
        return angular.fromJson(data).events;
      },
      isArray: true
    }
  });
});
```

And usage

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, JsonResource) {
  // No direct assignment here, resolve first, then assign
  JsonResource.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.events = data;
  });
});
```

Should work just fine with your `JSON` format.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "events": [{
    "id": 2234, 
    "number": 43545, 
    "name": "random"
  },{
    "id": 2235, 
    "number": 43546, 
    "name": "random"
  }]
}
```

See related Plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/Geklnp

Comment: `return angular.fromJson(data).events;` - Stupid me, just assumed the JS response would be decoded! No wonder I had no rows to iterate over!

Answer (score -1):

In the worst case you can transform with `javascript`

```
transformResponse: function (data) {

var arrayData = [];
   for( var i in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            arrayData .push(data[i]);
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: IN the controller: `console.log( BetClient.query() );` command gives me this object: `[$promise: Object, $resolved: false]`, but I want to get back my array :D

Comment: BetClient.query(function(data){
console.log(data)
})